# MongoDB - Killed when database disk is full

Tags: replication, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB 3.6.5 (already tested on 3.2 / 3.4) and i have enabled "directoryPerDB" in **/etc/mongo.conf**.

```
#mongod.conf

storage:
   dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
   journal:
     enabled: true
   directoryPerDB: true
```

I created LVM disk's for my databases and symlinked in to **/var/lib/mongodb**

Here is problem:

When one of these lvm's is full, it will kill **mongod service**, so i can't use the rest of databases, where is free space on storage. Because of that, this will kill my primary node and subsequently the secondary node.

Is there some way to deal with it ?

**Your help will be greatly appreciated!**

Comment: Also cross-posted to DBA, which is the most appropriate StackExchange site given the MongoDB context: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/210947/mongodb-killed-when-database-disk-is-full

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs you could just create one big LVM and mount that to  */var/lib/mongodb* and create folders on the big LVM. That would give all databases access to full capacity.

Another approach would be to overprovision the single LVMs for each database. Either use more physical space for the LVMs as actually needed or make use of LVM's thinpools.
Where the first approach would be very static and a waste of space usage.
 Using thinpools would open the possibility to add physical storage as needed at a later time.
Both approaches need a good planning and still might not meet your needs. One might also have to resize the LVM and filesystem when space gets low, which is always a critical path on a production system.

I think it is also possible to run multiple instances of *mongodb* which then should only affect the single instance when running out of space. But I think that would also mean to run the instances on different ports which makes things more complicated.

Another idea would be to switch to *btrfs* or *zfs*. Both filesystems have a similar approach to LVM, but it is much easier to add or remove space from a volume and you do not have to grow/shrink the filesystem. So it is much more flexible but comes at the cost of higher complexity.

In any case, you want to monitor the space usage with Nagios, Icinga2, Prometheus or TICK stack or whatever monitoring you want to use. Depending on your needs, you also could run a script when a limit of space is reached taking care of the situation.

For myself, I would go with the first option using just one big LVM and creating folders in there. Secondly I would go for *zfs* or *btrfs* as these filesystems give you the ability to manage your storage space easily without resizing LVMs and filesystems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! If i want to try run multiple instances of mongodb, do they need multiple "admin" databases and so on ? Can they log in to same log file ?

Comment: I don't know mongodb very well, but derived from other databasesI think you have different admin databases. While you could use the same logfiles, I would not recommend that.

Comment: All the ideas are interesting and helpful, but none of them are fit for us. Thank you for your try !